# Using Facebook Connect (which is in Objective C) in C++ code

Tags: c++, objective-c, facebook

I have already created a button widget in my game. When I press it, I want a dialog pop up, asking the user to login in with their Facebook account.

I've already downloaded Facebook iOS Connect, but it is written purely in Objective C. My game project is written in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're targeting iOS, in which case you can compile your code as Objective-C++, which basically allows you to use both languages together. Try changing your `.cpp` files to `.mm` files.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-cpp-graph-api/
It is an implementation of the facebook graph api in facebook. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: ...that is implented in qt framework .. so I don`t need that ..but thanks any way..~